# Firebase database exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang...' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already searched everywhere and tried their methods on how to invoke a virtual method but the result is still the same. Please help me, I don't know where my mistake is.

When I run my app on a phone, it throws the following Exception:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Stringmypackage.studentInformation.getUserID()' on a null
>   object reference

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //FirebaseAuth
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            userID = user.getUid();
        }
        //Realtime Firebase
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference newData = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        //Display data
        newData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    showData(dataSnapshot);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
}
```

Method showData()

```
 private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            studentInformation studentData = new studentInformation();
            studentData.setUserID(ds.child(userID).getValue(studentInformation.class).getUserID());
            studentData.setStudentFullName(ds.child(userID).getValue(studentInformation.class).getStudentFullName());
            studentData.setStudentID(ds.child(userID).getValue(studentInformation.class).getStudentID());
            studentData.setEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(studentInformation.class).getEmail());
            studentData.setCampus(ds.child(userID).getValue(studentInformation.class).getCampus());
            studentData.setCourse(ds.child(userID).getValue(studentInformation.class).getCourse());
            studentData.setIntake(ds.child(userID).getValue(studentInformation.class).getIntake());
        }
    }
```

Class studentInformation()

```
package mypackage;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class studentInformation {

    private String userID;
    private String studentFullName;
    private long studentID;
    private String email;
    private String campus;
    private String course;
    private String intake;

    studentInformation() {
    }

    studentInformation(String userID, String studentFullName, long studentID, String email, String campus, String course, String intake) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.studentFullName = studentFullName;
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.email = email;
        this.campus = campus;
        this.intake = intake;
    }

    public String getStudentFullName() {
        return studentFullName;
    }

    public void setStudentFullName(String studentFullName) {
        this.studentFullName = studentFullName;
    }

    public long getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(long studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCampus() {
        return campus;
    }

    public void setCampus(String campus) {
        this.campus = campus;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getIntake() {
        return intake;
    }

    public void setIntake(String intake) {
        this.intake = intake;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}
```

Firebase Database:
I export it and I changed from json to txt.

```
{
  "main" : {
    "home" : {
      "announcement-date" : "jkljlkjdaj",
      "campus" : {
        "unikl-miit" : {
          "course" : {
            "bcem" : {
              "courseName" : "BCEM"
            }
          }
        },
        "unikl-mimet" : {
          "course" : {
            "bse" : {
              "courseName" : "BSE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "student" : {
    "6LKSe5oqfwgrkEV57NXQekDvNhl1" : {
      "campus" : "UniKL MIIT",
      "course" : "Diploma In Animation",
      "email" : "hazman@gmail.com",
      "intake" : "55",
      "studentFullName" : "haMan",
      "studentID" : 52213116153,
      "userID" : "6LKSe5oqfwgrkEV57NXQekDvNhl1"
    },
    "evPFfkE1VtObUlBNz8pizSNKt662" : {
      "campus" : "UniKL MIIT",
      "course" : "Bachelor of Multimedia Technology (Hons) in Interactive Multimedia Design (BIMD)",
      "email" : "fakyou@gmshit.com",
      "intake" : "69",
      "studentFullName" : "Adam",
      "studentID" : 52213116190,
      "userID" : "evPFfkE1VtObUlBNz8pizSNKt662"
    },
    "rcUgnUBqd4Xb3AxmngE3OD1BBpd2" : {
      "campus" : "UniKL MIIT",
      "email" : "hazman45@gmail.com",
      "intake" : "52/49/4",
      "studentFullName" : "jwjajs",
      "studentID" : 52213116153,
      "userID" : "rcUgnUBqd4Xb3AxmngE3OD1BBpd2"
    },
    "z46FjWQE8TRYiJxIexMkrp6gSYv2" : {
      "campus" : "UniKL MIIT",
      "email" : "zoowake97@gmail.com",
      "intake" : "16/9/18",
      "studentFullName" : "Eisom",
      "studentID" : 52213116132,
      "userID" : "z46FjWQE8TRYiJxIexMkrp6gSYv2"
    }
  }
}
```

Questions[Update]:

```
//FirebaseAuth
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            userID = user.getUid();

            DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student");
            DatabaseReference currentUserRef = usersRef.child(userID);
            currentUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    studentData = dataSnapshot.getValue(studentInformation.class);

                    //studentID I delcared outside the onCreate. Does the 'studentID' store from Firebase?
                    studentFullName = studentData.getStudentFullName();//This one

                    textViewEmail.setText(studentData.getEmail());//Its working, display
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
                }
            });
        }
        //At 'onCreate'
        textViewStudentName.setText(studentFullName); //Can I do like this?
```

Updated 16/06/2018 QUESTION:

I want to make the value from Firebase Database inside new firebaseDatabaseCampus.

I made this one, and apps crashed. Please help me.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View viewMain = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_campus, container, false);

    recyclerView = viewMain.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewCampus);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));//Ini penting nak display

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();//Ini penting
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    //So retrieve data
    userID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
    databaseReferenceStudent = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("student").child(userID);
    databaseReferenceStudent.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //So sini kita ambik value campus ~ UniKL MIIT
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            studentData = new studentInformation();//Ini declare
            studentData = dataSnapshot.getValue(studentInformation.class);

            //1. So student.getCampus is here
            databaseReferenceCampus = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("campus").child(studentData.getCampus()).child("post");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return viewMain;
}

//On Start
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<campus, CampusViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapterCampus =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<campus, CampusViewHolder>(
                    campus.class,
                    R.layout.campus_row,
                    CampusViewHolder.class,
                    databaseReferenceCampus     //So the value getCampus is here?
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(CampusViewHolder viewHolder, campus model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setDetails(getContext(), model.getImage(), model.getTitle(), model.getDate(), model.getShortDescription());
                }
            };
    //setAdapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapterCampus);
}
```

Comment: It looks like `ds.child(userID)` does not contain a `studentInformation.class`. For more help, update your question to include a snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done updated.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hello Sir, can you check my latest question in here? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading all data from the root and then iterating over the children. Instead you'll want to read one level lower, in the `student` node:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
rootRef.child("student").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

**Update**: I now get the feeling you're just trying to read the data of the current user. In that case, the code is:

```
if (user != null) {
    userID = user.getUid();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");
    DatabaseReference currentUserRef = usersRef.child(userID);
    currentUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            studentInformation studentData = dataSnapshot.getValue(studentInformation.class)
            ...    
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but the result still the same. same exception. there is no changes.

Comment: Yes! its working! I have a question, can I use the value from `public void onDataChange()` , outside from it. You can check my question, I updated it.

Comment: By the time your `textViewStudentName.setText(studentFullName)` runs, the `studentFullName` hasn't been set yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Comment: Which one would you prefer? This one or that one you gave it to me?